# Firebase different security rules for different child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have my data structure like this.

[image]

**I want** that only admin can create a new user,
only admin can write expireDate,
Admin and user both can write other two fields,

**I tried these dabase rules:**

```
{
  "rules": {

      "users":{

              "$uid": {

                ".read": "auth.uid == $uid || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()",

                "expireDate":{
                                        ".write": "root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()"
                },

                "firstLoginAttempt":{
                    ".write": "auth.uid == $uid || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()"
                },

                  "macAddress":{
                    ".write": "auth.uid == $uid || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()"
                }


      } 
      }
```

I allowed admin to write for all child but admin is unable to create a new user. I know firebase database rules override in cascade, But how to implement here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you grant a user (read or write) access at a certain level in the JSON tree, you can no longer take that permission away at a lower level in the tree.

This means that:

1. Either the data that more people can write should be at a lower level in the JSON tree.
2. Or you will need to put the data in different top-level notes based on the requires access level.

Since your data structure doesn't follow the guidance of #1, so that mean you should follow #2.

Something like:

```
users: {
  user1: { ... },
  user2: { ... }
expiries
  user1: { ... },
  user2: { ... }
```

And then secure access between these two top-level nodes with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()",
    },
    "expiries":{
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()",
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got it, but I have a question, Why admin is unable to write in users, as all fields are open for admin??

Comment: Nobody is able to write in `/users` according to your rules. Access is granted on `/users/$uid`. But if you have a problem writing with these new rules, open a new question and [include the rules, JSON, and the minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).